# Phone "+" signal replaced frinto "3663"

Tags: android, android-intent

I got a problem on the `DIALER` in some device models I don't own to test, the problem is about phone number formatting.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "+55 11 4436-7602"));`
```

For some reasion, the `DIALER` is replacing `+` for `3663`

Down here is a screenshot from a user with that bug:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: May be problem with Dialer app, i tested your code in two device it shows the exact number which you have used in code.

Answer (score 0):

Client was using a different environment wich I didn't had access,

value for the intent was coming like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "Fone: +55 11 4436-7602"));`
```

The solution is filter the values coming form the API